# Compiling inconsolata on my mac produces wonky zero slash (Overleaf okay)

Tags: fonts, pdf, mac

**Update:** I checked the fonts in both PDFs, and they are slightly different (Ansi from my Mac, and Custom from Overleaf):

[image]

More info:

```
$ pdffonts main_mac.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
MOHEGW+SFRM1000                      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      10  0
LMEIEC+Inconsolatazi4-Regular        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       8  0


$ pdffonts main_overleaf.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
YBPMEZ+Inconsolatazi4-Regular        Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       4  0
VZMLCI+SFRM1000                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no       5  0
```

----- original post-----:

I've been working on a document on my Mac (pdfTeX, TeX Live 2017) and also on Overleaf (pdfTeX, TeX Live 2016). The inconsolata font has a screwed up 0 in the PDF on my Mac:
[image]

I cannot figure out from the log diff where the problem is on my side. Here is a test document that produced the output above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\begin{document}
\Huge{\texttt{0123456789}}
\end{document}
```

Here is the diff of the two logs:

```
$ diff main.log main_overleaf.log
1c1
< This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.5.23)  28 DEC 2017 11:18
---
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.12.15)  28 DEC 2017 19:20
3c3,4
<  restricted \write18 enabled.
---
>  \write18 enabled.
>  file:line:error style messages enabled.
7,8c8,9
< LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
< Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
---
> LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
> Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
32c33
< File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
---
> File: utf8.def 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
39c40
< File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
---
> File: t1enc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
251,252d251
<    defining Unicode char U+0232 (decimal 562)
<    defining Unicode char U+0233 (decimal 563)
273,274d271
<    defining Unicode char U+1E20 (decimal 7712)
<    defining Unicode char U+1E21 (decimal 7713)
280c277
< File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
---
> File: ot1enc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
321c318
< File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
---
> File: omsenc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
345c342
< Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
---
> Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package
348c345
< File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
---
> File: t1enc.def 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
352c349
< Package: inconsolata 2017/01/04 v1.112
---
> Package: inconsolata 2016/02/22 v1.10
354c351
< `inconsolata-zi4' v1.112, 2017/01/04 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe)
---
> `inconsolata-zi4' v1.10, 2016/02/22 Text macros for Inconsolata (msharpe)
356c353
< Package: textcomp 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
---
> Package: textcomp 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package
376c373
< File: ts1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
---
> File: ts1enc.dfu 2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc
511,523c508,510
< (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
< Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
<
< (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
< (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
< \XKV@toks=\toks16
< \XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17
<
< (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
< \XKV@depth=\count87
< File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
< ))
< \zifour@ocount=\count88
---
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
> Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
> \KV@toks@=\toks16
525c512,513
< (./main.aux)
---
> \zifour@ocount=\count87
> ) (./main.aux)
542c530,531
<  (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
---
>
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
554,558c543,544
< File: t1zi4.fd 2016/12/29 T1/zi4 (Inconsolata)
< )
< LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/zi4/m/n' will be
< (Font)              scaled to size 24.88pt on input line 6.
<  [1
---
> File: t1zi4.fd 2014/06/22 T1/zi4 (Inconsolata)
> ) [1
560,561c546
< {/usr/share/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main
< .aux) )
---
> {/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux) )
563,566c548,551
<  1552 strings out of 492995
<  19131 string characters out of 6132704
<  65466 words of memory out of 5000000
<  5132 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
---
>  1320 strings out of 493013
>  15201 string characters out of 6135681
>  60163 words of memory out of 5000000
>  4900 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
569,575c554,560
<  27i,4n,19p,174b,119s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
< {/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1
< .enc}{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/inconsolata/i4-t1-0.en
< c}</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/inconsolata/Inconsolat
< a-zi4r.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm
< 1000.pfb>
< Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 16112 bytes).
---
>  25i,4n,19p,173b,119s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
> {/usr/share/
> texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/f
> onts/enc/dvips/inconsolata/i4-t1-0.enc}</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/typ
> e1/public/inconsolata/Inconsolata-zi4r.pfb></usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public
> /cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb>
> Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 12755 bytes).
```

p.s. I get the same output using `latexmk main` or `latexmk main && dvipdf main.dvi`

Comment: Are the screenshots from the same viewer? If not, try opening in another one. In my computer the result is correct...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Both Preview and Adobe Acrobat Pro have the same incorrect output for the doc created on my Mac, but the correct output for the doc created with Overleaf. Indeed, opening the document on my Linux box does not show the artifact. Now I'm curious what Overleaf is doing differently to force the correct font (possibly including it in the PDF)?

Comment: See my update -- the fonts that both embed are different (Ansi -vs- Custom). Not sure how to get the custom from my Mac.

Comment: Strange, indeed. What I noticed is that the version of the `inconsolata` package is different. I looked on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.1700.1371212031.5851.ctan-ann@dante.de) and found this: `This en­hance­ment of the In­con­so­lata pack­age, pro­vides reg­u­lar and bold weights, ad­di­tional glyphs and op­tions to con­trol slashed zero, up­right quotes and a shape­lier lower-case L.` But I don't really know if it has something to do with the problem.  Just guessing...

Comment: I don't see the issue (and the encoding is Ansi only when `dvipdf` is used, not `pdflatex`). Can you please add the output of `shasum -a 256 $(kpsewhich Inconsolata-zi4r.pfb)` on the Mac? Also the output of `tlmgr info inconsolata` would be useful.

Comment: Huh -- yes, I see that now. My version is newer. But @Herbert below has the newest version. At this point, I'm thinking that both of my Macs are screwing up the output, and it isn't the fault of LaTeX (although I would like to try and put non-compressed fonts into the doc, which seems to solve the issue).

Comment: @egreg shasum: `f0f850d5cd4441c94aaf0526eeefb74b1df32bb2cf8c80dde0eca8a8ca57e0ab  /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/inconsolata/Inconsolata-zi4r.pfb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see it with an up-to-date TL2017 (MacTeX)
Use `\listfiles`  as first line to compare your list which is at the end of the log file:

```
*File List*
article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
utf8.def    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
t1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
ot1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
omsenc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
fontenc.sty
t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
inconsolata.sty    2017/01/04 v1.112
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
ts1enc.dfu    2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
upquote.sty    2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verbat
im
t1zi4.fd    2016/12/29 T1/zi4 (Inconsolata)
```

Comment: Thanks -- my `\listfiles` output is identical.

Comment: try to reinstall the consolata package with the TeXLive Manager from the Mac.

Comment: Yup, reinstalling inconsolata worked. Cheers!